# Low Insulin but Normal Blood sugar

Tags: endocrinology, fasting, insulin, blood-sugar

What does is mean when fasting Insulin Levels are Very Low (0.7 uU/ml) but Fasting Blood sugar levels are normal 4.2 mmol

KD.